# Renaming Filenames In Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as

```
'310', 'D', '1', '0', 'Clowns.jpg', ?, '63527560196'
'311', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowns_102_x_102.jpg', ?, '63527560197'
'312', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowns_45_x_45.jpg', ?, '63527560197'
'313', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowns_80_x_80.jpg', ?, '63527560197'
'314', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowns_120_x_120.jpg', ?, '63527560198'
'315', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowns_180_x_180.jpg', ?, '63527560198'
'316', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowns_300_x_300.jpg', ?, '63527560198'
```

I want to rename the files called Clowns to Clowning so the data would look like this

```
'310', 'D', '1', '0', 'Clowning.jpg', ?, '63527560196'
'311', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowning_102_x_102.jpg', ?, '63527560197'
'312', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowning_45_x_45.jpg', ?, '63527560197'
'313', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowning_80_x_80.jpg', ?, '63527560197'
'314', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowning_120_x_120.jpg', ?, '63527560198'
'315', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowning_180_x_180.jpg', ?, '63527560198'
'316', 'D', '1', '1', 'Clowning_300_x_300.jpg', ?, '63527560198'
```

So I tried this

```
UPDATE new_images 
SET 
filespec = 'clowns100' + MID(filespec, 7, LENGTH(filespec) - 6);
```

However I got

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'clowns100'

Comment: Your example obviously differs from your spec, so which is right?

Comment: How `clowns100` relates with your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `REPLACE`

```
UPDATE new_images SET filespec = REPLACE(filespec, 'Clowns','Clowning')
```

- [MySQL Replace (*String Function*)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

**UPDATE 1**

the equivalent mysql code for your query is

```
UPDATE new_images 
SET filespec = CONCAT('clowns100', MID(filespec, 7, CHAR_LENGTH(filespec) - 6));
```

Comment: then why not use `REPLACE(filespec, '.jpg','Clowning')`? by the way replace is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring in SQL

```
 UPDATE new_images SET filespec = 'Clowning'+substring('Clowns.jpg', 7, len('Clowns.jpg') - 6) where filespec like 'Clowns%'
```